# Is there a way to either update or delete multiple model instances with a single call?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, loopbackjs

I'm wondering whether it's possible to either PATCH or DELETE multiple model instances at once with a single API request in Loopback.js. I *thought* I was able to do so via a call containing an array of the model instances to be updated, but apparently this doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Use these persistedmodel methods :

**1. UpdateAll**

```
PersistedModel.updateAll([where], data, callback)
```

[More info, check the official documentation](https://apidocs.strongloop.com/loopback/#persistedmodel-updateall)

```
PersistedModel.updateAll({
  field1: value1,
  field2: value2,
},
  data,
  function (err, info) {
    if (err) { console.log(err); }
    console.log(info, info.count); // shows number of udaptes
  })
```

**2. DestroyAll**

```
PersistedModel.destroyAll([where], callback)
```

[More info, check the official documentation](https://apidocs.strongloop.com/loopback/#persistedmodel-destroyall)

```
PersistedModel.destoryAll({
  field1: value1,
  field2: value2,
},
  data,
  function (err, info) {
    if (err) { console.log(err); }
    console.log(info, info.count); // shows number of items deleted
  })
```